# Instagram login with Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, authentication, instagram

I am trying to login using Javascript on Instagram's login page:
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/

I insert the username and password using the script below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'login';
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = 'password';
```

I have verified that the password I enter is correct using this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].type = "text";
```

When I trigger the click event using below script, on login button, it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
```

Comment: any Solution that works ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. When you input a password, it's in plain text, and gets encrypted before being sent to the server. All you're doing is changing the way the password is presented to you.